# Recursion - Java Programming

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out why the output is 321 and not 123. I have tried multiple times and looking out lecture slides but I still can't get the solution to this question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     printNumber(1);
}

public static void printNumber(int n) {
    if(n!=4) {
         printNumber(n + 1);
         System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not understand recursion read this sentence from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong with the above sentence. I have been trying to figure out why the answer is 321 and not 123.

Comment: try to go through the code step by step (as you were running it) and write on a paper `n` when you encounter `System.out.print(n)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each call to `printNumber` calls `printNumber(n+1)` *first*, and then prints something out. So `printNumber(n+1)` has already finished before `printNumber(n)` prints its number out.

```
main():
   printNumber(1):
       printNumber(2):
           printNumber(3):
               printNumber(4) // does nothing
               print(n) // "3"
               // printNumber(3) completes, returning control to printNumber(2)
           print(n) // "2"
           // printNumber(2) completes, returning control to printNumber(1)
       print(n) // "1"
       // printNumber(1) completes, returning control to main()
   // main() completes
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `n` is either 1 2 or 3.

What are you printing first, `n` or `n + 1`? You are printing `n + 1` first, then `n`. So the numbers must come out in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this result that you have placed the recursion call statement `printNumber(n + 1)`
before print statement `System.out.print(n)` so it will keep recursivly calling it until it reach `4` after that it will print numbers from last call `n+1` to `n` as in our example from `3` to `1`

try this :

```
public static void printNumber(int n) {
    if(n!=4) {
         System.out.print(n);
         printNumber(n + 1);
    }
}
```

you will find the output: `123`

The reason for that is at each recursion call it will print the number `n` then it will call it another time for `n+1` until it reach `4`.